# Javascript Mini Game with Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying a very simple version of the game "rock, paper or scissors" with javascript. (Mostly to learn functions and although i think my code makes sense and it should print in the console the outputs on each If Else statement it doesnt print anything.

Any hint?

Code below

```
const startGame = document.getElementById('start-game-btn');
const choicePlayer = ["Rock" , "Scissor", "Paper"];
const defaultChoise = "Rock";


function startTheGame(choicePlayer,defaultChoise) {

alert("Choose Rock , Scissor or Paper");

prompt(choicePlayer[0], choicePlayer[1]);

for (var i=0; i<choicePlayer.length; i++)  {
if(choicePlayer[i]===choicePlayer[0] || choicePlayer[i] === choicePlayer[1] || choicePlayer[i] === choicePlayer[2]) {
    console.log("asdf");
    return choicePlayer[i];

}

else  {

console.log("we choose for you");
return defaultChoise;

}
}

}


startGame.addEventListener('click' , startTheGame);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to save the user input from the `prompt` function, you should save it in a variable like so: `const result = prompt("text that will show in the prompt");`
you can check the snippet I added for a solution for a few other fixes.

```js
const startGame = document.getElementById('start-game-btn');
const choices = ["rock" , "scissor", "paper"];
const defaultChoice = "rock";

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function gameInit() {

  const playerChoice = prompt("Choose Rock , Scissor or Paper");

  if(choices.includes(playerChoice.toLowerCase())) {
    //return playerChoice;
    console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter(playerChoice));
  } else  {
    console.log("we choose for you");
    //return defaultChoice;
    console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter(defaultChoice));
  }

}


startGame.addEventListener('click' , gameInit);
```

```html
<button id="start-game-btn">Start</button>
```

Comment: thank you so much Sir!It works like a charm although the use of  the statement return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1); kinda confused me

Comment: that's a function to capitalize a string. it takes the first letter of a string turns into an upper case letter and then concatenate  the rest of the string

Comment: Cool! but i think we can use toUpperCase() method on the prompt function too? Like Const playerChoice = prompt("Choose Rock , Scissor or Paper").toUpperCase()
Also how comes and you dont need a for loop to navigate through all the options of the array so the function can check each choice?

Comment: `toUpperCase` method will turn all the string into upper case letters. and I used the `includes` method to check if the player choice is in the array

Answer (score 3):

`prompt` works by returning a value, meaning you should use it like this:

```
choicePlayer[0] = prompt("Player 1 - Choose Rock , Scissor or Paper", choicePlayer[0]);

choicePlayer[1] = prompt("Player 2 - Choose Rock , Scissor or Paper", choicePlayer[1]);
```

Plus - having a function argument called `choicePlayer` will override your global variable `choicePlayer`, meaning that the `choicePlayer` inside the function holds the `event` argument.

Comment: thank you so much! i am so new to this! so either i create the choice array inside the function or i just dont use it as parameter on the () of function?